# Decode Nodemailer SMTP response

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses, nodemailer

[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/usage/) returns a response, which is

> a string returned by SMTP transports and includes the last SMTP response from the server

An example:

> response: '010001668cbaf1d3-7fadface-8253-49c5-ba34-dbb320d8a770-000000'

How should I decode this response (i.e. to understand if it succeeded or failed, and failure reason)?

Comment: That is not a *complete* SMTP response, which necessarily begins with 3 decimal digits followed by a single space, so it sounds like the module is being a little bit too "helpful" and has removed at least that code... but this does look like the format of a message-id generated by SES.  What is in the rest of the `info` structure?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `envelope` containing the FROM and TO addresses, `messageId: <same string as response>@email.amazonses.com` and a raw buffer that contains the content of the mail.